# Donot redirect to json code without debbuging the code

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect json method from jquery .Its working fine while putting debugger or putting alert box but not able to redirect without debugger
plz suggest solution for this 
thanks

//jquery code

```
 function ValidateMeetingOwner() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });      
    debugger;
    var flagValue;
    var value = $("#meetingowner").val();
    if ($("#meetingowner").val() != "") {
        $.ajax({

            dataType: "json",
            url: '/MeetingForm/ValidationMeetingOwner',
            data: { Id: value },
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                if (result.result1 == "False") {
                    debugger;
                    flagValue = result.flag;
                    alert(result.flag);
                    alert(result.result1);
                    alert("Pleas Enter valid user for Meeting Owner");
                    $("#meetingowner").val("");

                }

                else {
                    flagValue = "1";
                }
            }
        });
        if (flagValue == "0")
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
```

//Controller code

```
public JsonResult ValidationMeetingOwner(string Id)
    {
        string result1 = string.Empty;
        string flag = string.Empty;
        var IfExist = dbcontext.Users.Any(x => x.Name == Id || x.Id == Id || x.Email == Id);
        if (!IfExist)
        {
            result1 = "False";
            flag = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            result1 = "True";
            flag = "1";
        }

        return Json(new { result1, flag }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Try `async: false` in `ajaxSetup`

Comment: i have tried that already. But that is not working.

Comment: Try adding - `type: "POST"` in your ajax, then `[HttpPost]` attribute above your action method

Comment: tried that also... but not working.  :(